# python facebook-sdk posts with location

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the [python facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) and want to find all posts in my news feed that have a location tagged. To get all posts in my news feed, I know I can use this:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(USER_TOKEN)
feed = graph.get_connections("me", "home")
```

According to [facebook's API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post/) if I want only posts with locations I need to add the argument 'with=location' to the end of the url generated by

```
feed = graph.get_connections("me", "home")
```

But when I try

```
feed = graph.get_connections("me", "home", with='location')
```

I get

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `with` is a python keyword, you can't use it as a keyword argument in a function call, as in:

```
any_function(with=5)
```

or in my case:

```
feed = graph.get_connections("me", "home", with='location')
```

The function definition for [`get_connections`](http://facebook-python-library.docs-library.appspot.com/facebook-python/_modules/facebook.html#GraphAPI.get_connections) in the python facebook-sdk is

```
def get_connections(self, id, connection_name, **args):
```

Which means you can send `with` as a keyword argument by doing the following:

```
graph.get_connections('me','home', **{'with':'location'})
```